# does django have lots of clash if not isolated

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-staticfiles, django-static

I'm very new to django and web dev in general. I'm following tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-FTlQ7Djqc&index=1&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ib4HsrXEYpQnTOTZE1x0uc create a blog by 'The Net Ninja'. His django version is 1.x but I'm using 2.1
I have completed it and have successfully emulate it on my own by following along.
But I wanted to make another on my own.
 After I created it the files in my static files(the pictures for background) are clashing with my previous project.
Now background photo of my new project shows in previous project (both projects have static files in similar named folder )
So am I supposed to use virtualenv and is this kind of clash normal??? please help

Comment: actually its all sorted out now. I was referring to a wrong variable which confused my program and everything got mixed. It was a typo 

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean with "clash". If you configure both installations to point to the same static files location, then, yes, you might have some "clashes". You can just make them point to separate folders.

As for virtual environments, it's generally a good idea to have a separate one for each project. This way you can isolate your dependencies better. This is especially important if you're going to run different versions of Django concurrently where some third party apps might not work on all versions.

Comment: they are not pointing to the same static files... Both projects are in different directories and have different static files